# How to iterate a string in order to validate values are in range using charAt()?

Tags: java, string, validation

I am trying to iterate a string that contains the users inputed values. I want to validate that the user only enters 4 characters and that all of them are between 1 and 4. For example, prompts the user to enter 4 values using commas, therefore they can only enter 1,2,3,4. If they enter anything else, then they will be asked again. I have included the section of my code where I am trying to perform the validation. I am also experiencing an unreachable code error which does not make sense to me. This takes place after I close the while (true) loop.

```
        //Entering by ROWS
    //This is for a 4x4 board size using rows
        if (dataSelection == 1) {
        if (boardSize == 1) {
            int row = 1;
            while (row < 5) 
            {
                String row1Values4x4 = "-1";
                while (true) 
                {
                    Scanner firstRow4x4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Please enter four values using commas for row " + row); //this needs to loop
                    row1Values4x4 = firstRow4x4.next();
                    row1Values4x4 = row1Values4x4.replaceAll(" ",""); //this is in case user enters numbers with spaces
                    for (int i = 0; i < row1Values4x4.length(); i++) {
                        char c = row1Values4x4.charAt(i);
                        if (row1Values4x4.length() == 7 && c == 48) //I entered 48 in order to test if it is using ascii value (48 = 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } //I think I need to include another break in order to escape the second loop? 
                String strArray[] = row1Values4x4.split(","); //This is where I get an unreachable code error 
                int arraySidesInteger[] = new int[strArray.length];
                for (int i = 0;  i < strArray.length;  i++) {
                    arraySidesInteger[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
                }
                fourArray[row-1] = arraySidesInteger;
                for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < fourArray.length; j++)
                        System.out.print(fourArray[i][j] + " ");
                    System.out.println();
                }
                row++;
                }
```

Please let me know if there

Comment: Why are you using a matrix?

Comment: `//I entered 48 in order to test if it is using ascii value (48 = 0)`

fwiw, you could do `c == '0'` instead of `c == 48`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I am using a matrix or 2 dimensional array in order to sort the users input by row and column. Its for a 4x4 Sudoku game.

Comment: @DennisMeng I have tried that as well. For some reason my for loop or something is not iterating through the inputed values or something. It does not recognize that I am temporarily trying to restrict the inputed to only 0 values for testing purposes.

Comment: Well, that's because that isn't what you're asking it to do. You're asking it to break if the string is 7 characters long and the current character you are reading is a `0`. What exactly are you trying to do in that loop?

Comment: @DennisMeng Would you have any reccomendations if I wanted to restrict those inputed values to only 1-4? I tried including: if (row1Values4x4.length() == 7 && c > 48 && c < 53) but it does not work. Is that not allowed in Java? Or would I have to manually input '0' '1' '2' '3' '4'?

Comment: Well first, you should just do the length check outside of the `for` loop, you're currently checking it multiple times unnecessarily. Second, you *can* use `48` and `53` instead of `'0'` and `'5'`, but it's bad style to do so and reduces readability.

Comment: @DennisMeng Yeah I def agree with you. Okay, so I now check the length after before the code; however, I do not understand why it wont restrict all of the characters to only 1-4 even after I include the if (c > '0' && c < '5')? The for loop is set up correctly right? Im pretty sure that iterates through all of the characters.

Comment: Remember that you want to break out if the character is *not* within the range. If you are doing `for (...) {if (c > '0' && c < '5') break;}` then you're actually breaking *because* it's within the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is right; you need a second `break` in there. The `break` that exists only breaks out of the `for` loop, but not the `while` loop.

Perhaps instead of

```
while (true) 
{
    // do some stuff
    for (/* some other stuff */) 
    {
        // even more stuff
        if (/* should we break */) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

you could try something like

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) 
{
    // do some stuff
    for (/* some other stuff */) 
    {
        // even more stuff
        if (/* should we break */) 
        {
            done = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis! That cleared the problems I was facing. Would you have reccomendations if I wanted to restrict those inputed values to only 1-4? I tried including: if (row1Values4x4.length() == 7 && c > 48 && c < 53) but it does not work. Is that not allowed in Java? Or could I manually input '0' '1' '2' '3' '4'?

Comment: An even nicer way is to move the loops into their own functions. E.g. a function `isDigit`, so that you can use `return` instead of `break`. You might as well use `Character.isDigit` then, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the split method in strings

```
String s = userInput;
String[] inputArray = s.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
    // check if the character is correct here
}
```

Comment: A good point, and definitely does make things easier for the OP once he fixes the "unreachable code" issue.